# How to measure margin between font-elements in XD?

Tags: adobe-xd

It seems not possible to view the exact margin between font-elements in XD (dev-view). Below you'll find a screenshot of a situation where we need to measure the exact distance between two Font-elements (XD developer-view).

[image]

It needs to bypass the line-height, but it doesn't. To be able to do this, we need the line-height to be zero. But when we edit the line-height in XD for a word or sentence on a single row, XD does not change that line-height.

Anybody encountered the same situation?

In this example the line-height is 32. We go to XD. Change it to zero, save it and SHARE FOR DEVELOPMENT. But the line-height remains 32. Also changing it to 1 instead of zero won't make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

To fix this issue, you have to select the Text within Adobe XD. Right Click and select Path > Convert to Path. The margins around the Text will disappear and when in DEVELOPMENT view it becomes possible to see the right margin. A small problem remains. When you want to edit the text when it's a shape, you have to delete it and place a new text and turn it into a shape again. [the text when converted to a shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrkcY.png)

Answer (score 1):

The default selector in Adobe XD will not give you the exact margin between two text. You have to convert the text layer into paths (Convert to Outlines) to get the exact margin.
But remember after converting text layer into path the text cannot be edited because now the letter are separate vector shapes.

To convert text layer into Path, select the layer and goto Object>Path>Click Convert to Path

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Guides to drag one below your text and another one on top of the second text, and then you can see the distance between the 2 guides.

Check [this youtube video](https://www.adobe.com/products/xd/learn/design/tools/artboard-guides-align-and-position.html) for a quick tutorial on it. This is going to be a manual action. I don't think there's a key to press to check the distance automatically.